# how to create search function without link database

Tags: php, codeigniter

Actually  i tried to create search function without link to db. so the al thing i just put at model. now i don't know how to call that data in controller. hope anyone can solved my problem.

this my view page:

```
<li>Category:
<div>
<? echo form_dropdown('fcategory', $content_category); ?> </div></li>

<li> Channel:<div>
<? echo form_dropdown('fchannel', $content_channel); ?></div> </li>

<li> Language<div>
<? echo form_dropdown('flanguage', $content_language); ?></div> </li>

<input type="submit" class="btn" name="search" value="Search" /> <span class="lightfont"></span>
```

and this my model:

```
function general(){

    $data['content_category'] = array(
        "Dramas"=>"Dramas",
        "Movies"=>"Movies",
        "News"=>"News",
        "Anime"=>"Anime",
        "Popular Selection"=>"Popular Selection"
    );

    $data['content_channel'] = array(
        "China"=>"China",
        "Hong Kong"=>"Hong Kong",
        "Taiwan"=>"Taiwan",
        "Japan"=>"Japan",
        "Korea"=>"Korea",
        "UK"=>"UK",
        "US"=>"US",
        "Indonesia"=>"Indonesia"
    );


    $data['content_language'] = array(
        "English"=>"English",
        "Chinese"=>"Chinese",
        "Others"=>"Others"
    );

    return $data;
}


function sample_data(){

    $TVContent ['China']['Chinese']['Movies'][1]= array ('title'=>'Gooddrama','home-index-china movies', 'English', 'Grey');
    $TVContent ['China']['Chinese']['Drama'][2]= array ('title'=>'Gooddrama','home-index-china drama', 'English', 'Grey');
    $TVContent ['China']['English']['Sport'][3]= array ('title'=>'ABO','', 'English', 'Grey');
    $TVContent ['China']['Chinese']['News'][4]= array ('title'=>'KTD','', 'Chinese', 'Grey');

    $TVContent ['China']['Chinese']['Movies'][1]['title'];
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: a very bad idea to dump all your data in array only....

Comment: @BhuvanRikka  when user search the detail fro dropdown like drama, english, china. so it should show like Gooddrama,home-index-china movies, English, Grey. this just a a few data i show. hope u can help me as well :(

Comment: @itachi really...mybe you can suggest the better way for me.

Comment: @itachi yup... but this  is a part of my internship project. so i just follow the requirement.hope u can help me to solve this

Comment: @nurfariezza put more sample data. atleast 5 and that too from different categories

Comment: @itachi i already add that code. now i'm more2 cnfius..

Comment: @itachi i just focus for the china only. b'coz one country have a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Database to store your data will be the best implementation

This how you can call model function from the controller

//Load your model

$this->load->model('product_model');

//calling the model function

$this->product_model->your_function();

For more information,
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: thanks in advance. its working. but it show the all thing at my model.so,  how to display the certain thing what i need.